# How can I pass checkbox onclick event to parent onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a `<div>` with an `onclick` event and `<checkbox>`, `<span>` and `<img>` inside it.
When I click on the checkbox then the div-onclick event doesn't fire - I would like it to fire without having to duplicate the `onclick` onto the checkbox.

```
<div id="id-tag" onclick="do()">
  <span>text</span>
  <img src="pic.jpg" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" />
</div>
```

I know the div-idtag but ideally would like to avoid specifying it inside the checkbox.
Using another function call on the checkbox `onclick` to call the parent is NOT what I am looking for, like

```
onclick="run_parent_onclick()"
```

but this is okay (untested):

```
onclick="this.parent.click()"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fire the div's click event manually in the input's onclick:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" onclick="this.parentNode.click()" />
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" onclick="document.getElementById('id-tag').click()" />
```

Comment: Both work, but only if the checkbox is NOT disabled and I was having mine as disabled to control the checkedstate as the div onclick function can be cancel which means a user is able to check the box and cancel the function while the checkbox remained checked. Guess I have to think of something else to prevent this.

Comment: Be aware that DOM `.click()` only works on some elements in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Use addEventListener:

```
function do(e) { ... }
document.getElementById('id-tag').addEventListener('click', do, true);
```

The "true" makes the event capture.

Comment: How does that bind the checkbox onclick event to the parent div onclick action ?
Also I got hundreds to thousands of such divs, which why I am looking for something "global" as my untested example.